# I'm receiving undeclared identifier when calling this function from the free function outside of the contract

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

     

function taker(uint a, uint b) pure returns(uint s) {
     s = a + b;
     return s;
}
 

contract seeing {

     function see() public view returns (bool) {
        uint s = taker();
         return true;
         
     }
}
```

Comment: What's the exact error message? and what solc version are you using? I tried with solc 0.8.x and 0.7.1 and it worked. I got "TypeError: Wrong argument count for function call" because `taker()` requires two parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass 2 intergers on `taker`. e.g. `uint s = taker(1,2);`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to post the full code to get a more conclusive answer, but first thing I see is that you haven't declared the above contract (or interface/library) into the seeing contract.

You'll need code that looks something like this:

```
contract seeing {
  function see() public view returns (bool) {
    uint s = FirstContract(_contract).taker()
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: thats my exact issue.  According to the solidity rules The "free" function is allowed be declared outside of the seeing contract but im receiving undeclared identifier for some reason